# In css is there a shorthand notation for the text-... properties?

Tags: css

So, far as I know there are five different css text properties that can be applied.

`text-decoration`, `text-align`, `text-transform`, `text-shadow` and `text-indent`.

All with a variety of values. While applying four of these properties on a single element I was wandering, isn't there a shorthand notation for these properties? Something like:

```
text: none center uppercase 10px 2px 2px 2px #000
```

When I try something like the above code the rule gets ignored.

Comment: I seem to have found the answered myself and I guess the answer is "no", there is no mention of a text shorthand in the list of shorthand properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#see_also I'm leaving the question, maybe someone else has a similar question, otherwise a mod (or whatever you call them on stackoverflow) can remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not, you can check the "Text properties" of the [Css Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/).

Comment: Whenever I see  a reference to w3schools I vomit a little in my mouth, perhaps they have gotten better in recent years. But man, in my memory they are so bad!